# How do I set a custom Sec-WebSocket-Protocol using a C# ClientWebSocket?

Tags: c#, security, websocket, .net-5

I am attempting to authorize my connection to a 3rd party websocket host and they require a JWT be set as the protocol.

I am able to include the header like this but I am getting an error back. Is there a better way to do this?

```
var client = new ClientWebSocket();
client.Options.SetRequestHeader("Sec-WebSocket-Protocol", "my JWT");
await client.ConnectAsync(...);
```

The error I'm getting is something like this:

```
The WebSocket client request requested '' protocol(s),
but server is only accepting '...my JWT...' protocol(s).
```

My attempt at making this work in C# is unsuccessful although I am able to connect properly via Postman Websockets (beta) by just setting the `Sec-WebSocket-Protocol` header and then Postman figures out the other headers automatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution that seems to have worked is that I am not allowed to set the `Sec-WebSocket-Protocol` header myself. I must use the `client.Options.AddSubProtocol("my JWT")` instead.